# Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments works but SpecialFolder.MyComputer doesn't work?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio, special-folders

I am using VS2013 Express for Desktop and using Windows Forms.

I am following [this MSDN Walkthrough "Creating an Explorer Style Interface with the ListView and TreeView Controls Using the Designer"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171645.aspx). So I am trying to get the treeview to start from the "MyComputer" level, so that all the drive letters are available for the user to pick.

It works for MyDocuments, as follows:

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));
```

But it doesn't work when I pick MyComputer from the autocomplete:

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer));
```

I get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: The path is not of a legal form.

This is surprising because "MyComputer" is available in the autocomplete, but doesn't work like the other specialfolders.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
Thank you ByteBlast and CodyGray.

Would it be appropriate to ask here what I should do instead?

Comment: This would be a good time to learn how to use a debugger. Create an extra variable and put the result of Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer) into it. Then use the debugger to inspect what you get back.

Comment: @gus: I'm facing the same problem.Did you find any solution or alternative?

Answer (score 6):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) states that:

> The MyComputer constant always yields the empty string ("") because no
>   path is defined for the My Computer folder.

Supplying an empty string to the `DirectoryInfo` constructor is what causes the `ArgumentException`.

[Elsewhere on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) you can find an explanation as to *why* an empty string is returned :

> A folder will not physically exist if the operating system did not create it, the existing folder was deleted, or the folder is a virtual directory, such as My Computer, which does not correspond to a physical path.

Comment: Facing the same problem. What's the solution or alternative please?